# Remove leading trailing non numeric characters from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to strip off all the leading and trailing characters from a string upto the first and last digit respectively.

Example : `OBC9187A-1%A`
Should return : `9187A-1`

How do I achieve this in Java?

I understand regex is the solution, but I am not good at it.
I tried this `replaceAll("([^0-9.*0-9])","")`
But it returns only digits and strips all the alpha/special characters.

Comment: `Regex` would be a good place to start...

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post your attempts? Also explain problem you are having while creating solution. You simply need regex which will find `digit` `one or more of any characters` `digit`. This doesn't seem like very complex thing.

Comment: I edited my question to include what I have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a self-contained example of using `regex` and `java` to solve your problem.  I would suggest looking at a regex tutorial of some kind [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) is a nice one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String test = "OBC9187A-1%A";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d.*\\d");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Match: " + m.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Match: 9187A-1
```

`\d` matches any digit `.*` matches anything 0 or more times `\d` matches any digit.  The reason we use `\\d` is to escape the `\` for `Java` since `\` is a special character...So this regex will match a digit followed by anything followed by another digit.  This is greedy so it will take the longest/largest/greediest match so it will get the first and last digit and anything in between.  The `while` loop is there because if there was more than 1 match it would loop through all matches. In this case there can only be 1 match so you can leave the `while` loop or change to `if` like this:

```
if(m.find()) 
{
    System.out.println("Match: " + m.group());
}
```

Comment: I used a similar expression with replaceAll, but it did not work, returned only digits.

Comment: @user2166045 what expression did you use?

Comment: @user2166045 in this case you could use `replaceAll` there are 2 examples below but since you are trying to pull out a match from the `String` I would use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` to match a portion of your `String`.  This allows you to keep the original `String` if you want or you can replace it `myString = m.group();` with the matched `String`.

Answer (score 3):

This will strip leading and trailing non-digit characters from string s.

```
String s = "OBC9187A-1%A";
s = s.replaceAll("^\\D+", "").replaceAll("\\D+$", "");
System.out.println(s);
// prints 9187A-1
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/O64x8Q)

Regex explanation
**^\D+**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
\D+ match any character that's not a digit [^0-9]
     Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
```

**\D+$**

```
\D+ match any character that's not a digit [^0-9]
     Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
  $ assert position at end of the string
```